# Parsing multiple nested arrays using Codable protocol

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I have nested arrays coming in my API response and I am having following response.

> **Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.**

My Api response is somethings like that.

```
    {
    "FatherModel": {
        "UserId": 7340,
        "ParentType": "Father",
        "PartnerId": 0,
        "EducationId": 1,
        "User": {
            "Id": 7340,
            "FirstName": "xxx",
            "LastName": "x",

        }

    },

   "Students":{
   "Id" :0
   "Enrollments":[
     { "Id": 1605,
       "StudentId": 1935,
       "ClassId": 0,
      }
]
},
```

As you can see there is tree of arrays with nested objects and custom arrays, I have made the class models in this way...

```
class FatherModel {
var UserId : Int? = nil
.... ..
......
var user : UsersModel.? = mil
var Students : [StudentModel] = nil

}

similarly is with UsersModel
now here comes the student Model array 

class StudentModel {

var Id = Int? = 0
var Enrollments = [EnrollmentModel]
}


and 

class EnrollmentModel {
var id : Int = 0
......
}
```

but I am having error and this is 
**Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.**

what I am doing wrong here ?

**Note:**

> The Structures, classes and JsonString is just a demo to make you understand the problem. Please help me.

Comment: somewhere the structure broken with the response with your classes

Comment: The error message cleary says that you are going to decode an array `[StudentsModel]` but the corresponding object is actually a dictionary `"Students":{ ...`. JSON is a very simply data format, `[]` is array, `{}` is dictionary. And check your spelling `StudentsModel` != `StudentModel` and variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: yes I know . It was just demo. But yes you are right. The issue was I was parsing the array the issue was it was simple model

Comment: Would be a lot easier for us to help you if you could post _actual_ and valid code... Even if the code is for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @Alladinian check my comment above. With help of vadian I solved my problem

Comment: @Androidteem I know... my point is that other users facing similar problems might benefit from this post, and having invalid code doesn't help...

Comment: o that is great thinking